# checkbox value. getting strange value when checked/unchecked

Tags: jsf

i have  a checkbox in jsf as follow. this jsf page is in the portal page.
when i check the checkbox i get value as "on" and when i uncheck it i get the value as null. Why is it like that. the code is as below:

the checkbox is in formitem. isFullTimeStudent is of type Boolean

```
> <hx:formItem styleClass="formItem"
> id="fullTimeStudentFormItem"
>      showHelp="none"
>      label="&nbsp;&nbsp;#{giamsBundle['lbl.full.time.student']}">
>      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="fullTimeStudentChkBox"
>       value="#{pc_AssigneeDependents.dependent.isFullTimeStudent}"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
>     </hx:formItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `on` is the default HTTP request parameter value for a checked checkbox. You're apparently grabbing it raw from the request parameter map instead of accessing it by the property as bound by the input element's `value` attribute.

Don't use the request parameter map, just access it in the `AssigneeDependents` managed bean by `dependent.getIsFullTimeStudent()` which in turn should be a `boolean` or `Boolean`.

Comment: Thanks Balus,
i am using ajax on my page and i cant submit my page. thus have to get the values from the parameters. so when i check the checkbox i get on and when i uncheck i get null.